# Dojo REST calls returning weird error

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm using the [DOJO](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/ajax/) library to make Ajax calls to the [BING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158961.aspx) elevation service. The calls are being made [successfully](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/Polyline?points=-84.44627894973615,33.79093896172691,-84.43705215072468,33.80377767236137&heights=sealevel&samples=10&key=AvzoZIkNO45p0W_CsBKNrKFALLA0IZcmI7XJ2QRTF87X8Gt0wloV1xQ0BdINIHN_&callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script26) , 200 error, but the return function/data is breaking.
I've tested this by making calls to a non BING service and JSON data was returned with out problem. But when calling the BING service I get:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

error an error in the console, which points to a returned sheet from the BING service that contains [this data](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/Polyline?points=-84.44627894973615,33.79093896172691,-84.43705215072468,33.80377767236137&heights=sealevel&samples=10&key=AvzoZIkNO45p0W_CsBKNrKFALLA0IZcmI7XJ2QRTF87X8Gt0wloV1xQ0BdINIHN_&callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script26).

**ultimate problem: ajax call from dojo to REST service is showing unseen results, has anyone encountered this, and or have a solution?**

Dojo Ajax snippy:

```
request.get('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/Polyline?points=-84.44627894973615, 33.79093896172691, -84.43705215072468, 33.80377767236137&heights=sealevel&samples=10&key=BINGKEY', {
    jsonp: 'callback'
}).then(function(returned) {
    console.log('call has completed: ' + returned);
}).error(function(msg) {
    console.log('there was a problem retrieving elevation data: ' + msg);
});
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell bing that you are using JSONP

The jsonp parameter in dojo is supposed to map to the name of the jsonp call back parameter for the api you are calling,  for bing maps its jsonp.

ex

```
request.get('https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Elevation/Polyline?points=-84.44627894973615, 33.79093896172691, -84.43705215072468, 33.80377767236137&heights=sealevel&samples=10&key=BINGKEY', {
    jsonp: 'jsonp'
}).then(function(returned) {
    console.log('call has completed: ' + returned);
}).error(function(msg) {
    console.log('there was a problem retrieving elevation data: ' + msg);
});
```

Comment: I tried that before, and now again and I get an even stranger message: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** If anyone would have CORS resolved on their boxes it'd be BING??

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a CORS-related error if you are actually using `dojo/request/script` as in tik27's fiddle, which is what you need to use for a JSONP service.  That's the point of JSONP - it operates via script injection rather than XHR to avoid the cross-origin restriction.